# Which API keys do I need for a cordova application to use Google Maps?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm currently developing on brackets for programming and Xcode for project management. My application runs but the notification for an invalid maps key comes up on launch. I have included my js API key for the application in my index.html file, and I checked the credentials to see if it was enabled and it is. I don't know if I also need the iOS one, and if I do I don't know where to put it for the application. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. I am already 100% sure that the html is correctly written and that the API key is in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hybrid mobile app, Google [suggests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key) using file:// referrers.

> `file://` referers need a special representation to be added to the key restriction. The `file://` part should be replaced with `__file_url__` before being
>   added to the key restriction. For example, `file:///path/to/` should
>   be formatted as `__file_url__//path/to/*`.

For Apache Cordova on iOS I suggest:

iOS 9 and earlier - `file: ///www/default` 
iOS 9.3 - `file: ///var/containers`

Note that there is a small risk involved in authorizing URLs under the "file" protocol. If anyone knew your API key, they could potentially use it from their application provided they used the same path. For this reason Google recommends that you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations.

Hope this helps!